# Show that if $e^{iθ1} = e^{iθ2}$ then $ θ_1 = θ_2 + 2kπ$ for some integer k.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing

Show that if $e^{iθ1} = e^{iθ2}$ then $ θ_1 = θ_2 + 2kπ$ for $k \in \Bbb{Z}$ .

Is Mathematical Induction a viable way to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use induction. We have $e^{it}=1$ where $t =\theta_1-\theta_2$. So $\cos t=1$ and $\sin t =0$. In each of the intervals $[2\pi k, 2\pi (k+1)]$  the only points where $\cos t=1$ and $\sin t =0$ are $t=2k \pi$ and $t =2(k+1) \pi$.

Comment: Further, mathematical induction is only used under natural numbers

Answer (score 1):

No, mathematical induction is not a viable way.

Let $t_1,t_2 \in \mathbb R$ . If $e^{it_1}= e^{it_2}$, then $e^{i(t_1-t_2)}=1.$ Hence

$$ \cos(t_1-t_2)=1$$

and

$$ \sin (t_1-t_2)=0.$$

The last equation gives $t_1-t_2= j \pi $ for some $j \in \mathbb Z.$ From the first equation we derive $1= \cos (j \pi)=(-1)^j,$ Thus $j=2k,$ with $k \in \mathbb Z.$ It follows that

$$t_1-t_2= 2k \pi.$$